# How to write SOQL query Group by apex enterprise pattern

Tags: enterprise

Normal soql query:working fine

```
List<AggregateResult> leads=[
    SELECT LeadSource, COUNT(id)
    FROM Lead
    GROUP BY LeadSource
];
```

Apex enterprise pattern query - **not working**

```
set<string> Emails= new set<string>();
Emails.add('test@test.com');
Emails.add('test@test1.com');
Emails.add('test@test2.com');

fflib_QueryFactory query = newQueryFactory();
query.setCondition('Email IN:Email Group by GROUP BY LeadSource);
return (Database.query( query.toSOQL()));
```

***Expected result:***
[image]

Comment: what do you mean "not working" ? any exceptions ? can you provide example of expected and actual result

Comment: Ordered field must be grouped or aggregated:"error"  is came

Comment: Can you `System.debug(query.toSOQL());` to see if its valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments in [`fflib_QueryFactory`](https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-apex-common/blob/master/fflib/src/classes/fflib_QueryFactory.cls), at line 48:

> - Current limitations:
>
>   - Aggregate functions are not currently supported.

You won't be able to build this aggregate query using this class.

Your attempt is failing in this case because you have a `GROUP BY` clause, but no grouping established in your `SELECT`.